# Как управлять блоком audio из другой вкладки или определить статус этого блока?

Tags: jquery, javascript, html5, вкладки, аудио

Доброго времени суток, #Хэш и его посетители.

На одной из страниц моего сайта у меня воспроизводится аудиофайл. Если быть точнее - один из трёх файлов. Сам файл выбирается динамически пхп-кодом (использую шаблонизатор Smarty), в зависимости от некоторых данных, при открытии страницы. Но все три файла записываются в аудиоблок с одним ID. Выглядит это так:

```
<audio id="PageSound" preload="auto">
    <source src="./sounds/{$sound}.mp3"></source>
    <source src="./sounds/{$sound}.ogg"></source>
</audio>
```

Однако информация на странице тоже разная может быть. В зависимости от переданных данных в GET-запросе. То есть сам адрес страницы может быть разным. Выглядит это так:

`mysite.ru/Page.php?data="get-data"`

Из-за того, что информация может быть разная, пользователи могут открывать сразу несколько вкладок с различными GET-параметрами, для сравнения информации на страницах. В связи с этим, происходит воспроизведение аудио на всех вкладках, и как побочный эффект - наложение звука из разных вкладок. Вы сами понимаете, насколько это неудобно. Моя задача - убрать это наложение звука. В мою пустую голову не пришло ничего лучше, чем поизвращаться с куками. Итак:

```
function playTimePageSound()
{
    var playTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    playTime += 5;
    setCookie('PageSound', playTime, 1);
    window.setTimeout(playTimePageSound, 4000);
}
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    var nowTime = new Date().getTime() / 1000;

    PageSoundStatus = getCookie('PageSound');
    if(PageSoundStatus == undefined)
        PageSoundStatus = 0;

    if(PageSoundStatus < nowTime)
    {
        var PageSound = document.getElementById('PageSound');
        PageSound.play();
        playTimePageSound();
    }
});
```

При открытии страницы я проверяю время, записанное в куке. Если оно меньше текущего времени, то воспроизвожу звук. Как только начинает воспроизводиться звук, то каждые 4 секунды в куку записывается время, больше текущего на пять секунд. То есть если я открою новую вкладку со страницей или обновлю текущую в течении пяти секунд, то на новой звук воспроизводится не будет. После закрытия текущей страницы у меня будет фриз 5 секунд. Проблему это решило. При открытии нескольких вкладок звук воспроизводится только на первой открытой. Однако тут появляется ряд проблем.

1. Это чересчур извращённо - каждые четыре секунды обновлять куку.
2. Если аудиофайл остановится или пользователь его остановит вручную, то скрипт на обновление куки продолжит своё существование и работу.
3. После закрытия страницы ждать до пяти секунд, чтоб звук начал воспроизводится на новых открываемых страницах - ну как-то не фонтан.

У меня появилась мысля, может, есть какая-то возможность проследить открытые окна/вкладки браузера со страницей `mysite.ru/Page.php` и статусом воспроизведения блока `<audio id="PageSound">`? То есть я хочу определить, если где-то в каком-то окне или вкладке с такой страницей, воспроизводится аудио-файл, то новый не будет запускаться. Если нигде не воспроизводится, то начинаем воспроизведение. Так как воспроизведение файла может быть остановлено с помощью `PageSound.pause();`, то это надо также учитывать, как блок, который не воспроизводится (например `if(PageSound.paused){}`).

Или, как вариант, создать глобальный объект, доступный во всех окнах/вкладках браузера. Например в ВК такая фича реализована. При начале воспроизведения медиа-файла в одной вкладке, в другой вкладке воспроизведение медиа-файла приостанавливается.

Я надеюсь на вашу помощь и поддержку. Заранее всем спасибо.

С уважением, Юрий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак. Весь вчерашний день я провёл в гугле и на многих форумах. Читал много и долго. Приходилось даже ковырять английскую документацию, хотя я не знаю английского. Натыкался на различные комментарии пользователей сообществ, доходило до таких идей, как использование HTML5 History API, однако это не то. Это решало проблему с переходом по страницам не прекращая музыку, а не с её управлением из других вкладок. В общем на одном из форумов мне ответил добрый гик. :)

> Коммуникацию между вкладками браузера можно организовать подписавшись на изменение данных localstorage и записывая нужные команды в него.

Погуглив `localStorage`, нашёл одну его особенность, о которой упомянул тот гик: `localStorage` кидает событие изменения, которое можно отловить. Само изменение никак не остановить, однако сообщения о нём вполне достаточно.

Хранилище `localStorage` представляет собой ассоциативный массив из пары `ключ => значение`

Сегодня повозился с двумя мануалами на разных сайтах и изменил свой JS-код до такого состояния:

```
function PageSoundPlay()
{
    var nowTime = new Date().getTime();
    var PageSound = document.getElementById('PageSound');

    localStorage['PageSound'] = nowTime;

    PageSound.play();
}
function PageSoundStop()
{
    PageSound.pause();
    PageSound.currentTime = 0;
}
function onStorageEvent(storageEvent){
    if(storageEvent.key == 'PageSound')
        PageSoundStop();
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("storage", onStorageEvent, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent("onstorage", onStorageEvent);
    };
   PageSoundPlay();
});
```

Что я делаю? При открытии страницы я запускаю отслеживание событий хранилища, после этого запускаю воспроизведение музыки. Попутно определяю текущее Unix-время и записываю его в локальное хранилище в виде пары  `PageSound` и `nowTime`:

```
localStorage['PageSound'] = nowTime;
```

Если я открою новую страницу, то переменная `PageSound` получит новое значение, так как Unix-время не стоит на месте. :)

Старая страница получит сообщение об изменении события, и если ключ изменённого события равен `PageSound`, то останавливаю воспроизведение `PageSound.pause();`.

Таким образом это не является управление элементами другой вкладки. Просто создавалось такое впечатление, что я могу управлять элементами другой вкладке. На самом-то деле, это просто отслеживание изменения локального хранилища, и если оно где-то меняется, то, так как оно общее, другая страница может получить уведомление об этом, и запустить действия, задуманные кодером для определённых ситуаций. :)

Открыв контактовский скрипт `common.js` с помощью поиска текста нашёл там отлов событий localStorage. Видимо так они и останавливают музыку в других вкладках. Я решил свою проблему, так что вопрос решён. Если мои поиски кому-нибудь пригодятся - я буду рад, что создание этого вопроса было не напрасным. :)

Всем спасибо, всем удачи. Если есть какие-то вопросы - пишите сюда, отвечу. :)

---

Ссылки на мануалы:

[Локальное хранилище на htmlbook.ru](http://htmlbook.ru/html5/storage)

[Attaching a Storage Event Listener в теме HTML5 Local Storage](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/local-storage.html#attaching-a-storage-event-listener)

Comment: Вот это хороший, правильный пример целенаправленного достижения цели!..

Comment: @deivan спасибо. Приятно. :)

Как-никак проблема была, и кровь из носу надо было её решить. Готовлю к запуску браузерную онлайн игрушку.